# how can i change the character case (lower to upper and vice versa)? at the same time

Tags: text-processing

input

```
   > a='Vikas'
   > echo $a
    Vikas
```

my required output is

```
echo $a | <some command>

vIKAS
```

Comment: Looks like homework to me

Comment: very simple, use `tr` command..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo Vikas | LC_ALL=C tr a-zA-Z A-Za-z
vIKAS
```

The utility `tr` translates characters; it takes two arguments representing sets of characters; it then copies standard input to standard output replacing each character found in the first set with the corresponding character in the second set. In this application, it replaces lowercase letters with uppercase letters and vice-versa. See the [manual page of tr(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tr.1.html) for details and for other processing which `tr` can perform.

Comment: what is `LC_ALL=C` @AlexP,   without that its also giving same output

Comment: thanks Alex. 

> echo Vikas | tr [a-z][A-Z] [A-Z][a-z]
vIKAS


can you please say why LC_ALL=C is required ?

Comment: Without setting the locale to `C`, the meaning of `a-z` and `A-Z` is unknown, since these ranges are locale dependent (for example, in some locales this will also include non-ASCII characters). Setting it to `C` guarantees that these ranges mean what most people expect.

Comment: @VikasVenna: Many utilities interpret a range such as `A-Z` as representing all characters which sort between `A` and `Z` in the current locale. Your `tr` may do this or not, I don't know. By setting `LC_ALL=C` I am certain that `A-Z` means `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use tr command with [:upper:] and [:lower:] options, like this:

```
echo "aBcDeF" |tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'
AbCdEf
```

also you can use sed command (stands for 'Stream editor'), like this:

```
echo "abcd ABCD" |sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```

sed has more flexibility, it means you can define any character mapping. for example you can convert numbers to hackers letter with this command:

```
echo "52065218802365" |sed 'y/0123456789/OIZEhSGLBP/'
SZOGSZIBBOZEGS
```

[(character mapping reference)](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet#Numbers_for_letters)